# Cast automático com TypeScript?

Tags: php, mysql, ionic, typescript, cast

### Direto ao ponto:

Existe uma maneira de realizar cast automático utilizando uma interface como modelo no Ionic (TypeScript + Angular 5)?

Se não, é possível fazer o Lint reconhecer que um objeto vindo do servidor não está dentro do contrato de interface esperado?

### Cenário:

Estou utilizando Ionic (Angular versão 5) e um backend em PHP. Meu problema é na hora de tratar os dados vindos do servidor usando uma interface que criei.

Eu tenho duas interfaces que trabalham juntas:

```
export interface QuestionInterface {
    id_question: string,
    answers: Array<AnswerInterface>,
    question_text: string
}

export interface AnswerInterface {
    answer_text: string,
    is_correct: boolean
}
```

Dentro da aplicação, tudo funciona perfeitamente e recebo os alertas quando tento usar tipos que não estão no contrato. O problema é quando os dados chegam do servidor.

```
http.get('xxx')
.toPromise()
.then(result=> {

})
```

A requisição retorna um objeto que contém, em `result.data`, dados de uma tabela. Porém, como a coluna `is_correct` é do tipo `tinyint(1)`, esses dados chegam pra mim como "0" ou "1".

Não queria ter que fazer o cast manualmente, porque acho muita gambiarra. Alguém consegue pensar em alguma forma de realizar uma conversão "automágica"?

Caso contrário, como fazer o objeto que vem do servidor passar por uma verificação de contrato com a interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode usar:

```
result.data.is_correct == "1"
```

```js
var x = "1";
console.log(x == "1");
x = "0";
console.log(x == "1");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/TypeScript/StringType.ts).

Comment: Dois problemas: vou ter que varrer todos os objetos e não queria ter que fazer isso; os tipos são string, não number e esse teste sempre vai ser true. Eu entendo que posso fazer esse casting manualmente, mas queria evitar, se houvesse um meio de realizar esse cast.

Comment: Ah, sim. Resolve o segundo problema mas,ainda assim, preciso varrer os elementos todos. Se der pra evitar...

Comment: Acho que aí você quer mágica.

Answer (score 0):

Voce pode criar uma propriedade a mais na sua interface assim

```
is_correct:number;
is_correct_bool: boolean;
```

Ai depois pode usar o

```
this.QuestionInterface.answers.forEach(element => {
        element.is_correct_bool = element.is_correct == "1" : true ? false;
});
```

Nesse exemplo o "QuestionInterface" seria a sua variável desse tipo ... depois de receber o retorno em JSON.

Assim ia ser feito de uma vez sem precisar passar manualmente 1 a 1.